# reduceByKey returns different value every time

Tags: mapreduce, pyspark

I have a key value data, let's call this *x*. It consists of a key, and a pair of volume and weight. It looks like this

```
[('t1', (2, 0.8)),
 ('t1', (3, 0.1)),
 ('t1', (4, 0.3)),
 ('t2', (3, 0.8)),
 ('t2', (10, 0.3))]
```

I want to calculate the weighted volume value, for each t1 and t2. That is I calculate

2 * 0.8  +  3 * 0.1  +  4 * 0.3  for t1

3 * 0.8  + 10 * 0.3 for t2

I can do

```
x.map(lambda (x, (y, z)): (x, y*z)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).collect()
```

I would get the correct number

```
[('t2', 5.4), ('t1', 3.1)]
```

My question is, if I use the original input x, and run a reduceByKey operation such as

```
x.reduceByKey(lambda (f1, w1), (f2, w2): (f1 * w1 + f2 * w2, w1 + w2)).collect()
```

I was hoping to get

```
[('t2', 5.4, 1.1), ('t1', 3.1, 1.2)]
```

However, I'm getting different results every time I run the reduceByKey operation:

```
[('t2', (5.4, 1.1)), ('t1', (3.38, 1.2000000000000002))]
[('t2', (5.4, 1.1)), ('t1', (2.2, 1.2000000000000002))]
[('t2', (5.4, 1.1)), ('t1', (2.91, 1.2))]
```

What am I misunderstanding from the reduceByKey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break down -

t1 has three values ('t1', (2, 0.8)), ('t1', (3, 0.1)) and  ('t1', (4, 0.3))

during the first pass of reduceByKey, output will be -

```
(2,0.8),(3,0.1) => (2*0.8 + 3*0.1,0.8+0.1) == (1.9,0.9)
```

in next pass, it will be

```
(1.9,0.9),(4,0.3) => (1.9*0.9+ 4*0.3,0.9+0.3) == (2.91,1.2)
```

so, effective accumulation done here is `(2 * 0.8 + 3*0.1 )*(0.8+0.1) + (4 * 0.3)` instead of your intend which was `(2*0.8 + 3*0.1+4*0.3)`